# How to add a new line to a shell file above a specific line with sed

Tags: shell, jmeter, alpn

I want to add a new line for the file `apache-jmeter 4.0/bin/jmeter`

The last 2 lines of the file is as follows

```
 fi
 "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" $ARGS $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar. "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

I want to add a line above the last line of the file to make the output to be like as below

```
 fi
 #JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:/home/ubuntu/alpnboot.jar"
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" $ARGS $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar. "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Running JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) it's suggested to add such option to `setenv.sh` file:

> To set those variables permanently, you can place them in a file called setenv.sh in the bin directory. This file will be sourced when running JMeter by calling the jmeter script.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant sed command would be something like:

```
sed 's/^"\$JAVA_HOME\/bin\/java" \$ARGS \$JVM_ARGS \$JMETER_OPTS -jar "\$PRGDIR\/ApacheJMeter\.jar" "\$@"$/#JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath\/p:\/home\/ubuntu\/alpnboot\.jar"\n&/' jmeter
```

Remember that sed uses [Posix Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) therefore you will need to escape any of `$.*/[\]^` characters with a backslash.

---

If you're going to use [HTTP2 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-http2-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide) you can make the change permanent, this [`-Xbootclasspath`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/xbootclasspath.html) option will make no harm, there is not much sense in turning it on and off.